# How to write this query in Linq2Sql

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, select

I have a table company which holds the company_id, company_name and other details.
I have a table subcontracts which has a company_id column that maps to company.company_id.

How can I write a select statement to get all active companies which have not been assigned to an active subcontract?  IE  The company_id cannot be found in subcontracts.company_id

******EDIT*****

I believe the correct sql is:

```
select company_id 
from company 
where company.active_status = 1 
and not exists( select * from subcontracts 
                where subcontracts.company = company.company_id 
                AND subcontracts.active_status = 1
              )
```

Comment: I would write the SQL like: 
SELECT company_id FROM company c
LEFT OUTER JOIN subcontracts sc ON c.company_id = sc.company_id AND c.active_status = 1 AND sc.active_status = 1
WHERE sc.company_id is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub-select is pretty much the same in LINQ.

```
var noSubs = from company in context.Companies
             where company.active_status == 1 &&
                 !(from subcontract in context.Subcontracts
                  where subcontract.active_status == 1
                  select subcontract.company_id).Contains(company.company_id)
             select company;
```

Linq to SQL will translate this as a "not exists" on the subcontract table.

Answer (score 1):

Figure out how you would do this in standard SQL and then pick up a copy of Linqer (http://www.sqltolinq.com/). This product will convert almost any SQL statement into a LINQ query. It's not free, but not expensive either, and comes with a 30 day trial period. I have found it to be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to do a WHERE NOT IN, like maybe:

```
var companiesWithoutSubcontracts = 
        from noSub in Companies
        where !(from withSub in Companies
                select withSub.company_id)
               .Contains(noSub.company_id)
        select noSub;
```

`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var noContracts =
    from c in db.Companies
    join sc in db.Subcontracts.Where(sc => sc.active_status == 1) on c.company_id equals sc.company_id into compGroup
    from cg in compGroup.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    where cg.company_id == null
    select c;
```

This does a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. All subcontracts without a corresponding company_id will be assigned a `NULL` value for company_id, which it then selects.

Comment: Thanks.  I can get it where it's selecting companies with active_status == 1 that are not in subcontracts.company_id.  But, I can't seem to get it to work where it only matches subcontracts with active_status == 1.  Where do I put the where in the join?

Comment: @RememberME Edited to do what I think you want. This will also return companies with subcontracts that are inactive

Comment: You don't really need the join. LINQ to SQL is perfectly capable of handling a sub-select in the where clause.

Comment: @Jacob Proffitt At worst a join performs equally to a subquery, at best it is much more efficient than a subquery, especially when EXISTS is involved.

Comment: Oh yeah. I'm not judging the join *bad*. It's just not required.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it and it may well be that LINQ to SQL fails to translate the query, but in theory this should work.

```
var result = context
   .Subcontracts
   .Select(subcontract => new
      {
         Subcontract = subcontract,
         NotAssignedCompanies = context
            .Companies
            .Where(company => !company.Subcontracts.Contains(subcontract))
      });
```

This will return all not assigned companies for all subcontracts. If you only need the information for one specific subcontract, the following query will be sufficient.

```
var notAssignedCompanies = context
   .Companies
   .Where(company => !company.Subcontracts.Contains(specificSubcontract));
```